# Was it ever hinted in the books that Westeros was one of many continents?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-YUDNK7nUM) Cersei Lannister says:

> My only venture at this moment is establishing control over **this**
>   continent and every person on it.

I'm not sure, but by using **this** instead of **the**, they just implied that Westeros is one of many continents, and that everybody knows that as a fact. By everybody I mean at least those that Cersei is talking to.

There is been a while since I listened to the audiobooks, so don't quote me on this one, but I don't recall the author ever acknowledging the existence of more continents beside Westeros. Thus my question, was it ever acknowledged or hinted in the books that Westeros was one of many continents?

Comment: You realize the books came first, right; Are you looking for an answer from *A Song of Ice and Fire*? Also, Dany has spent most of her life on another continent... Essos...

Comment: @Skooba Yes, I know that, ...hmm I have to remove the book-adaptation tag.

Comment: The opening credits on the show also show at least two continents.

Comment: Er... Westeros and Essos have both been around since S01E01. I don't understand how this is confusing.

Comment: Even in the first book it's pretty clear there is more than a single continent.

Comment: @onewho I see... it's just that I don't want to listen to the audiobooks again, and I'm not familiar with the TV series.

Comment: @rraallvv Then what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @rraallvv You might want to try the [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) stack if you have not watched the TV series for your questions.

Comment: The people of Westeros are obviously aware that there are different continents, especially Essos, since it's just around the corner. Unless you're asking whether the term _continent_ is used in the narrative. That's a different story, although SF&F would be a better place to ask for that.

Comment: If you haven't watched the TV series, why do you ask this here?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Is having not watched the series a reason for not asking? If so, where is that stated?

Comment: @rraallvv, but you're asking a question about the books and not about the show, and that would make it rather off-topic....and shows little research on your part as well as there are several wikis that would answer the question.  The show has deviated quite far from the source material and anything in the show may not correlate with the books.

Comment: Nah, the books don't actually spend much time developing a backstory. I wouldn't bother reading them, they're *too short*!

Comment: Check out this [The Known World Map](https://i.redd.it/ap8fmgf1fzcz.jpg) - Google Maps Style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other major continent in "Planetos" is Essos, which has been shown in the opening credits since the first episode.

> [The title sequence](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Title_sequence) consists of a three-dimensional map of the world, with the continents of Westeros and Essos located on the inner surface of a sphere. At the center of the sphere is a light source, effectively a sun surrounded by an astrolabe-like arrangement of rotating rings. The details of the title sequence change each week depending on the locations visited.

If you are looking for the books to confirm this the name [Essos](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Essos) does not appear until *A Dance with Dragons*. However, "the lands across the Narrow Sea" are referred to several times and in several ways as this is where Daenerys has spent most of her life.

Answer (score 1):

The books and show have consistently referenced a second continent from the start: Daenerys begins her journey on a separate continent across the narrow sea: Essos.

There may even be more continents but the books get hazy beyond the region the story takes place in, leaving vague mentions of lands in the far east beyond any maps shown like Asshai. In the Fifth book **A Dance With Dragons** a man from a southern continent of Sothoryos is a fighter in the pits. And some consider the Summer Isles south of Dorne to be another small continent.

Westeros and Essos are clearly defined and present on most maps of the world though, as the story takes place on them both.

A map of the known world from http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Known_world
[image: The World of Ice and Fire]